# Can't install keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth, requires Rust?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, python-cryptography, google-artifact-registry

I tried to install the https://pypi.org/project/keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth/ package, but installation failed because it claims that Rust is required to install:

> `This package requires Rust >=1.41.0.`

How can I install this? Do I need to install Rust?

Full output is here:

```
$ pip install keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth

Collecting keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/02/9f28458631602cbc62c6d188c313ce81a2b796bc3eb4f4fa3e9c10e6e3b4/keyrings.google_artifactregistry_auth-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting keyring (from keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/f9/41230ac47f738f1ba66676dc8d3b30ca5b1f9eb0230fc204bcd9836c4ae9/keyring-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests (from keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/c1/24814557f1d22c56d50280771a17307e6bf87b70727d975fd6b2ce6b014a/requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting google-auth (from keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/c1/44179a1cfc5c3b5832a5f9c925161612471ec5f346bcd186235651d74f35/google_auth-1.30.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting importlib-metadata>=3.6 (from keyring->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/e2/49966924c93909d47612bb47d911448140a2f6c1390aec2f4c1afbe3748f/importlib_metadata-4.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting SecretStorage>=3.2; sys_platform == "linux" (from keyring->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/1e/29cd69fdac7391aa51510dfd42aa70b4e6a826c8cd019ee2a8ab9ec0777f/SecretStorage-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jeepney>=0.4.2; sys_platform == "linux" (from keyring->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/b0/a6ea72741aaac3f37fb96d195e4ee576a103c4c04e279bc6b446a70960e1/jeepney-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<5,>=3.0.2 (from requests->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/c7/fa589626997dd07bd87d9269342ccb74b1720384a4d739a1872bd84fbe68/chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/a0/5f06e1e1d463903cf0c0eebeb751791119ed7a4b3737fdc9a77f1cdfb51f/certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 (from requests->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/c6/d3e3abe5b4f4f16cf0dfc9240ab7ce10c2baa0e268989a4e3ec19e90c84e/urllib3-1.26.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5 (from requests->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/38/928ddce2273eaa564f6f50de919327bf3a00f091b5baba8dfa9460f3a8a8/idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.6" (from google-auth->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/93/0c0f002031f18b53af7a6166103c02b9c0667be528944137cc954ec921b3/rsa-4.7.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 (from google-auth->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bf/28/c4f5796c67ad06bb91d98d543a5e01805c1ff065e08871f78e52d2a331ad/cachetools-4.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.3.0 in ./env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google-auth->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth) (40.8.0)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 (from google-auth->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/de/214830a981892a3e286c3794f41ae67a4495df1108c3da8a9f62159b9a9d/pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.9.0 (from google-auth->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/5a/e7c31adbe875f2abbb91bd84cf2dc52d792b5a01506781dbcf25c91daf11/six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.4; python_version < "3.8" (from importlib-metadata>=3.6->keyring->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/35/6c4fff5ab443b57116cb1aad46421fb719bed2825664e8fe77d66d99bcbc/typing_extensions-3.10.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting zipp>=0.5 (from importlib-metadata>=3.6->keyring->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/8c/715c54e9e34c0c4820f616a913a7de3337d0cd79074dd1bed4dd840f16ae/zipp-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography>=2.0 (from SecretStorage>=3.2; sys_platform == "linux"->keyring->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/77/461087a514d2e8ece1c975d8216bc03f7048e6090c5166bc34115afdaa53/cryptography-3.4.7.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.3 (from rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.6"->google-auth->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/1e/a94a8d635fa3ce4cfc7f506003548d0a2447ae76fd5ca53932970fe3053f/pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi>=1.12 (from cryptography>=2.0->SecretStorage>=3.2; sys_platform == "linux"->keyring->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/2d/cd29c79f2eb1384577d0662f23c89d29621152f14bef8c6b25747785744b/cffi-1.14.5-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=2.0->SecretStorage>=3.2; sys_platform == "linux"->keyring->keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ae/e7/d9c3a176ca4b02024debf82342dab36efadfc5776f9c8db077e8f6e71821/pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl
...
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions, zipp, importlib-metadata, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, jeepney, SecretStorage, keyring, chardet, certifi, urllib3, idna, requests, pyasn1, rsa, cachetools, pyasn1-modules, six, google-auth, keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth
  Running setup.py install for cryptography: started
    Running setup.py install for cryptography: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /tmp/env/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-_54nhq8a/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-tfcrao8e/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /tmp/env/include/site/python3.7/cryptography:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/fernet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/__about__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography
    copying src/cryptography/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/oid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/ocsp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/general_name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/certificate_transparency.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/x509
    copying src/cryptography/x509/name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/x509
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/_oid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/_der.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/_types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/poly1305.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_cipheralgorithm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/keywrap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/_asymmetric.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/_conditional.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/concatkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/scrypt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/kbkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/hkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/x963kdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/ssh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/pkcs7.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/pkcs12.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ed448.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ed25519.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/x25519.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/x448.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/algorithms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/aead.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/hotp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/totp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ed448.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ed25519.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/aead.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x25519.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ocsp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/poly1305.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x448.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/encode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
    running egg_info
    writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'vectors'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.github'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'release.py'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'mypy.ini'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.zuul.d'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.zuul.playbooks'
    adding license file 'LICENSE'
    adding license file 'LICENSE.BSD'
    adding license file 'LICENSE.PSF'
    adding license file 'LICENSE.APACHE'
    writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    copying src/cryptography/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/cryptography
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/_padding.c'
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/_openssl.c'
    running build_rust
    
        =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
        If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
        successfully install cryptography:
        1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
           users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
        2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html for specific
           instructions for your platform.
        3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
           https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq.html
        4) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed:
           https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html#rust
        5) If you are experiencing issues with Rust for *this release only* you may
           set the environment variable `CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1`.
        =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
    
    error: can't find Rust compiler
    
    If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.
    
    To update pip, run:
    
        pip install --upgrade pip
    
    and then retry package installation.
    
    If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
    
    This package requires Rust >=1.41.0.
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/tmp/env/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-_54nhq8a/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-tfcrao8e/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /tmp/env/include/site/python3.7/cryptography" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-_54nhq8a/cryptography/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your `pip` version is too old to install one of this project's subdependencies, `cryptography`, which is using newer features.

Upgrading `pip` with the following will make it possible to install this package:

```
$ pip install -U pip
```